# awk : extracting a data which is on several lines

Tags: bash, awk

so I have a file that looks like this :

```
/translation="MDGVTQQNAALVQEATTAAASLEEQARNLTAAVAAFDLGDKQTV
                 LITPRAAVPALKRPALKASLPASSSHGNWETF"
                 /product="Methyl-accepting chemotaxis protein I (serine
                 chemoreceptor protein)"
 CDS             complement(471..590)
                 /db_xref="SEED:fig|1240086.14.peg.2"
                 /translation="MHQYQSAILAKICRYGGIEKPEITPASVYKLDSHWRYVI"
                 /product="hypothetical protein"
 CDS             717..2354
                 /db_xref="SEED:fig|1240086.14.peg.3"
                 /translation="MGFFVVLWGGASGFSLYSLKQVTTLLHDNSTQGRTYTYLVYGND
                 QYFRSVTRMARVMDYSQFSDAAIASLEEQAQQLTKAVEVFHLGSEYQTAAS
                 RTRPAGNMALKRPALSGMAPALPPARTASDEGSWEKF"
                 /product="Methyl-accepting chemotaxis protein I (serine
                 chemoreceptor protein)"
                 /product="macromolecule metabolism; macromolecule
                 degradation; degradation of proteins, peptides,
                 glycopeptides"
```

I need to extract the text that is between quotes after a "/product=", so I need this :

```
Methyl-accepting chemotaxis protein I (serine chemoreceptor protein)
hypothetical protein
Methyl-accepting chemotaxis protein I (serine chemoreceptor protein)
macromolecule metabolism; macromolecule degradation; degradation of proteins, peptides, glycopeptides
```

I have to use awk, so I wrote this :

```
awk '/\/product/ {split($0, a, "\""); printf a[2] "\n"}'
```

but this only takes the info on the same line as "/product", and some times the info is on two or three lines.. I'm out of ideas as to how to get the entire info between the quotes, anyone can help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`awk` to the rescue!  needs multi-char `RS` support (`gawk`)

```
$ awk -v RS='/| CDS' -F'"' '/^product/{gsub("\n +"," "); print $2}' file


Methyl-accepting chemotaxis protein I (serine chemoreceptor protein)
hypothetical protein
Methyl-accepting chemotaxis protein I (serine chemoreceptor protein)
macromolecule metabolism; macromolecule degradation; degradation of proteins, peptides, glycopeptides
```

**Explanation**
set the record structure (either starts with "/" or " CDS", find related records (starting with product), trim extra spaces and print the field between two quotes (second field based on set field delimiter to double quotes).

Answer (score 1):

**`Awk`** solution:

```
awk -v RS='"' '!(NR%2) && f{ gsub(/[[:space:]]+/," "); print }
               /\/[[:alnum:]_-]+=$/{ f=(/product=/? 1:0) }' file
```

- `-v RS='"'` - treat double quote `"` as record separator
- `!(NR%2)` - on each *even* line
- `gsub(/[[:space:]]+/," ")` - remove extra whitespaces(s)
- `f=(/product=/? 1:0)` - set the flag `f` in active state `1` on `/product= ...` lines

---

The output:

```
Methyl-accepting chemotaxis protein I (serine chemoreceptor protein)
hypothetical protein
Methyl-accepting chemotaxis protein I (serine chemoreceptor protein)
macromolecule metabolism; macromolecule degradation; degradation of proteins, peptides, glycopeptides
```

Comment: what does  /\/[[:alnum:]_-]+=$/ mean haha? and I don't get why you only want to deal with even lines?

Comment: @janedoe, what does mean your "*mean haha*"?

Comment: I meant "what does that mean" :)

Comment: @janedoe, `/\/[[:alnum:]_-]+=$/` - matches keyword/parameter which is preceding to double-quoted content, i.e. this line `CDS             complement(471..590) /db_xref="SEED:fig|1240086.14.peg.3"` will be separated into 2 adjacent parts

Comment: on even lines, this is because the line separator (record separator) was changed to `"` with `RS="` so even lines are inside double quotes and odd outside

Answer (score 1):

can be done with GNU grep, output separated by `\0` 0 byte

```
grep -Pzo '/product="\K[^"]*'  | tr -s '\0\t\n' '\n '
```

or perl replacing multiple (spaces, newlines or tabs) by a single space, separated with newlines

```
perl -0777 -ne 'print s/\s+/ /gr."\n" for /\/product="\K[^"]*/g'
```

Comment: @Sundeep, thank you for your catch, indeed the grep can be used only to pipe to `xargs -0` or a process which can split on 0 byte

Comment: added `|tr` to do the same as in perl

Answer (score 0):

With GNU awk for multi-char RS and RT:

```
$ gawk -v RS='/product="[^"]+"' -F'"' 'RT{$0=RT; gsub(/\s+/," "); print $2}' file
Methyl-accepting chemotaxis protein I (serine chemoreceptor protein)
hypothetical protein
Methyl-accepting chemotaxis protein I (serine chemoreceptor protein)
macromolecule metabolism; macromolecule degradation; degradation of proteins, peptides, glycopeptides
```

Answer (score -1):

assuming file name is **file.txt**

```
echo $(cat file.txt ) | sed 's/\//\n/g' | grep product | sed 's/product="//g;s/".*//'
```

**Explanation :**

1. merge all line into  one line

   **echo $(cat file.txt )**
2. replace "/"  as new line

   **echo $(cat file.txt ) | sed 's///\n/g'**
3. grep line which having line Product

   **echo $(cat file.txt ) | sed 's///\n/g' | grep product**
4. replace "product=" and all acaracter after double quote

   **echo $(cat file.txt ) | sed 's///\n/g' | grep product | sed 's/product="//g;s/".*//'**