# How to join different lines containing different patterns in UNIX?

Tags: bash, shell, unix, awk, pattern-matching

I have a file like this one:

```
/db_xref="SEED:fig|1240086.14.peg.1"
             /translation="MDGVTQQNAALVQEATTAAASLEEQARNLTAAVAAFDLGDKQTV
             LITPRAAVPALKRPALKASLPASSSHGNWETF"

/product="Methyl-accepting chemotaxis protein I (serine

chemoreceptor protein)"

CDS             complement(471..590)

/db_xref="SEED:fig|1240086.14.peg.2"

/translation="MHQYQSAILAKICRYGGIEKPEITPASVYKLDSHWRYVI"

/product="hypothetical protein"

CDS             717..2354

/db_xref="SEED:fig|1240086.14.peg.3"
```

and the result should be:

```
solanii.1    Methyl-accepting chemotaxis protein I (serine chemoreceptor protein)

solanii.2    hypothetical protein
```

I need to get all the lines that start with /product but if they don't end with " I need to get the next line too and then join them.
Also from each part fig|1240086.14.peg.1 I need to get the last number and replace the rest with solanii

I'm using this code to get everything that's written after product:

```
awk -v RS='/| CDS' -F'"' '/^product/{gsub("\n +"," "); print $2}'
```

but I do not know how to do the rest.

Comment: sample data is similar to that shown in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47653826/awk-extracting-a-data-which-is-on-several-lines and code used is from the accepted answer...

Comment: @Sundeep yes but there is one more thing I need to do that isn't asked in that question.

Answer (score 1):

Building on what you've got, I think this `awk` might work for you:

```
awk -v RS='/|CDS' -F'"' '
{
   gsub("\n", "") 
}
/^db_xref/ { 
   num = gensub(/^.*([0-9]+)"\s*$/, "\\1", "1") 
} 
/^product/ { 
   print "solanii." num " " $2 
}' input_file
```

**EDIT:** Better solution also using `awk` (thank you @EdMorton). Please note that this uses gawk-specific tools:

```
awk -v RS='/(product|db_xref)="[^"]+"' -F'"' '
RT{
   $0=RT
   gsub("\n", "")
   if (/^\/db_xref/) num = gensub(/^.*([0-9]+)"$/, "\\1", "1")
   else print "solanii." num " " $2 
}' file
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the answer I gave to [your last question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47653826/1745001):

```
gawk -v RS='/product="[^"]+"' -F'"' 'RT{$0=RT; gsub(/\s+/," "); print $2}' file
```

and here's how to modify it for your current question:

```
gawk -v RS='/product="[^"]+"' -F'"' 'RT{$0=RT; gsub(/\s+/," "); print "solanii." NR, $2}' file
```

again, it uses GNU awk for multi-char RS and RT

Comment: You start off by saying "Here's the answer I gave to your last question:", what makes you think that Maria and jane doe are the same person? I don't think are. Anyway, I see a potential issue with using `NR` vs the way PesaThe's answer gets the value for `db_xref`. Your answer essentially assumes the value for `db_xref` ends in `1` for the first record in the file, and while it logically should that doesn't mean it actually does in every use case for this data, and if it doesn't then the output is wrong in every instance. So, doesn't capturing the actual value seems a more prudent way to go?

Comment: Because she is asking to process the same data as in her previous question and using the answer she accepted to her previous question. She also just said in a comment `there is one more thing I need to do...`. No, my answer doesn't assume that, it just finds strings that look like `/product="[^"]+"` and prints them after converting every sequence of contiguous white space to a single blank char. No, relying on some other values than the specific target `product` value being present, as in PasaThe's answer which relies on both `db_xref` and `CDS` values being present, is a bad idea.

Comment: Whether or not its the same person is irrelevant but she said `Also from each part fig|1240086.14.peg.1 I need to get the last number and replace the rest with solanii`. While the example data does end with `1` that doesn't necessarily mean it always will as the first record in the file and that's the point I'm trying to make. Your code doesn't even look at `db_xref` and you use `NR` which assumes the value for that in the first record is `1`. Just for argument sake, if the first line in the sample input had `fig|1240086.14.peg.0` in it, your code produces `solanii.1` instead of `solanii.0`.

Comment: Absolutely correct, who it is is completely irrelevant so why are you dwelling on it? Ah, now I understand what you're talking about. If that's really an issue I'm sure the OP can tell us and produce more truly representative sample input/output.

Comment: I'm not dwelling on it, I simple asked what makes you think that Maria and jane doe are the same person because you started your answer with "Here's the answer I gave to your last question:" and the user id behind the two names are different, so it's not like the user changed their name as some do, it two different accounts, but could still be the same person. Anyway, IMO a given answer should do what was asked more so then wait for a user to come back and say, e.g "this somewhat works, but...",  and I'm just trying to learn something between the two approaches in the answers, that's all!

Comment: Every day we see questions where people ask for specific things that they absolutely don't need just because that's the only way they can think of solving a problem, often missing the simpler approach. If they've actually thought it through and do need a specific thing then they'll usually post sample input/out to reflect why that specific thing is needed.

Comment: I admit, I have never really done much `awk`. Your solution is much better and I really shouldn't rely on `RS='/|CDS'`. I simply tried to build on OP's code. I tried to adapt your solution in my updated answer to meet OP's needs (I hope I actually improved it). If you mind me building on your code, I will, of course, delete it immediately.

Comment: @PesaThe, All user posted content throughout Stack Exchange is released under the [Creative Commons](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.5/) license and you are free to do as you wish with it within the bounds of the license.

Comment: @PesaThe - no problem, have at it :-).